# Cannot read "includes" of undefined, while it is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a React component that will be displayed on the landing page. The component will display a string from the back office. If the string contains a specific chain, like `#age#`, this would trigger an ajax request to get the user's age, and then replace `#age#` by it.

My issue is that even though I can access my string, and it works with a string I created myself for some tests, it doesn't work when I work with `this.state`, saying it's undefined. I also can't make it work with [any function whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript).

Here is how I do this so far:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class homeLanding extends React.Component {

    state = {
        settings_data: [],
        user_data: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('settings_data') === null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/settings',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    self.setState({settings_data: data});
                    localStorage.setItem('settings_data', JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({settings_data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settings_data'))});
        }

    }

    render() {

        let welcome_title = this.state.settings_data.welcome_title; 
        // returns "welcome to site"

        if(welcome_title.includes('site')) {
            console.log('yaaaaaaay');
        } // error, cannot read includes of undefined
 return (
            <div className="col-md-10 main">
                <h1>{this.state.settings_data.welcome_title}</h1>
                <!-- Displays correctly the title -->
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My question is the following: why doesn't it work, and how can I make it so? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you tried to set the state in the constructor instead of using props initialisers?

Comment: Also your settings_data in an array and you are trying to access a property called welcome_title on it, that is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is **asynchronous**. Although you're *starting* your ajax call in `componentDidMount` (well, maybe; more on that in a minute), it doesn't *finish* then. It finishes later.

So if `componentDidMount` starts the call (in the case where you don't have settings in local storage yet) and then `render` is called, you're trying to use `this.state.settings_data.welcome_title` when `this.state.settings_data` is still its initial value, `[]`, which doesn't have `welcome_title`.

`render` should handle the case where you don't have the data yet, and then the case where you do, e.g.:

```
if (typeof welcome_title === "undefined") { // Or your favorite way of checking
    // ...you don't have it yet...
} else {
    // ...you have it and it isn't blank...
}
```

---

Separately: You're using `self` in the ajax callback in `componentDidMount`, but not setting it anywhere. That isn't why you're getting the error you're getting, but it could be why you'll get your *next* error (that you can't call `setState`).

You could use an arrow function and `this` instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('settings_data') === null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/settings',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: data => {                                               // ***
                this.setState({settings_data: data});                        // ***
                localStorage.setItem('settings_data', JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({settings_data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settings_data'))});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, all of you guys made me understand more about asynchronous, I thought that since I make a call on a local server, the ajax request won't take any time to be done. Well it doesn't, make it still is longer than the page loading.

Answer (score -1):

jquery is not definied

npm install jquery

`import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;`

then use

`$.ajax({
                url: '/settings',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    self.setState({settings_data: data});
                    localStorage.setItem('settings_data', JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });`

you can use or use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: As you can see I put my ajax in my localStorage so I don't make 458493 ajax call when I reload the page. So actually, thank you for making me notice but it didn't solve my problem